# How to debug javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

Somewhere In my javascritp and jquery code i am setting some property that causes internet explorer to crash but I cannot detect the line that causes this error to be raised as it is crashing in a jquery file that is not mine. I have seen in the stack trace but there is no useful information about the exact line that causes this error to be raised, the only it is saying is about a set that has been performed somewhere (but where¿?). so could someone tell me how can I debug javascript o jquery code efficiently to detect the source line that causes the error? and how to put breakpoints if it is possible. I am new on web app programming, javascript and jquery and things like that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Please**, do not downvote!

Comment: Console is your best friend. Learn to use it. Google, Youtube, etc... and by pressing F12 on your browser

Comment: If you post here some specific code we can also help. Use jsfiddle.net and build a example there of your problem and post back here.

Comment: [Debugging Script with the Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `alert(someVariable)` to see the value of some variable.

Better, you must learn to use Console with `console.log(yourVariable)`. In your browser, just open it with `F12` and look all the possibilities by yourself : you'll soon be addict to this tool !

Comment: Please don't suggest using `alert()`, this is a painful way to debug anything in any browser. Even IE comes with a pretty decent JS debugger and a console nowadays.

Comment: Please don't downvote, this is a painful act for someone who's trying to suggest ALL possibilitites to the author. I never say "you have to use `alert` ", I'd like to show the author all possibilities, as he asks. He will see by himself `console` is much better. This is called `self-learning` and this is the more efficient way to learn.

Comment: @AlexB i agree with you. Please, do not downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Install firebug and restart the browser. Turn on the firebug and rest you can follow using Google.

Comment: How does Firebug help debug a problem in IE?

Comment: Juhana ..looks like you are a little too eager to downvote ... go check firebuglite .. it works with IE6+  ..